# Can a gas be compressed to a higher density than its liquid counterpart?

Tags: pressure, temperature, phase-transition, states-of-matter

Given a volume of a gas (such as Hydrogen, or any other gas)
At near 0 Kelvin in temperature, and near 0 barometric pressure (vacuum).

Can the gas be mechanically compressed to such an extent, that the gas has a higher density than the same substance would have as a liquid at the same temperature?
Or is every gas guaranteed to condense into the literal liquid state before reaching the necessary pressure to achieve such density?

(If the gas heats up in the process of being compressed, I imagine this could complicate things.)

Comment: Triple point: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_point (related)

Comment: @Gert Thanks for pointing me there. From the diagram, it looks like the answer is "no" ...

Comment: The question you need to ask yourself is: what's the difference between a liquid and a gas which has been compressed to the density of a liquid?

Comment: See also, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercritical_fluid